# Run function every N seconds with context timeout

Tags: go, timeout, goroutine, go-context

I have a basic question about scheduling "cancellable" goroutines.

I want to schedule a function execution, every 3 seconds.

The function can take up to 5 seconds.

In case it takes more than 2999ms I want to stop/terminate it, to avoid overlapping w/ the next one.

I'm doing it wrong:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("startProcessing")
    go startProcessing()

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 60)
    fmt.Println("endProcessing after 60s")
}

func startProcessing() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(3 * time.Second)
    for _ = range ticker.C {
        ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), (time.Second*3)-time.Millisecond)

        fmt.Println("start doSomething")
        doSomething(ctx)
    }
}

func doSomething(ctx context.Context) {
    executionTime := time.Duration(rand.Intn(5)+1) * time.Second

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Printf("timed out after %s\n", executionTime)
            return
        default:
            time.Sleep(executionTime)
            fmt.Printf("did something in %s\n", executionTime)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This is my output now:

> startProcessing
>
> start doSomething
>
> did something in 2s
>
> start doSomething
>
> did something in 3s
>
> start doSomething
>
> did something in 3s
>
> start doSomething
>
> did something in 5s
>
> start doSomething
>
> did something in 2s
>
> ...

I want to read `timed out after 5s` instead of `did something in 5s`.

Comment: You can't abort `time.Sleep`. Context cancellation has no magic in it; all it does is fire a message on its `Done` channel when the timeout is reached. In order to cancel something, that something has to be checking that channel and stopping whatever it's doing. `Sleep` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the `time.Sleep(executionTime)` outside the `select` and there is no need for the `for` loop. I think this is somehow what you want but beware that *it's not good practice*. So take a look at the **warning** below.

```golang
func doSomething(ctx context.Context) {
    executionTime := time.Duration(rand.Intn(5)+1) * time.Second
    processed := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(executionTime)
        processed <- 1
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Printf("timed out after %s\n", executionTime)
    case <-processed:
        fmt.Printf("did something in %s\n", executionTime)
    }
}
```

**Obs**: I changed the original answer a bit. We can not interrupt a goroutine in the middle of its execution. We could delegate the long-running task to another goroutine and receive the result through a dedicated channel.

**Warning**: I wouldn't recommend that if you expect the processing time to exceed the deadline because now you will have a leaking goroutine.

Comment: That won't stop it though, that just means it prints a different message.

Comment: Yes! You are right. In addition, there is no way to stop/interrupt a goroutine. I changed the answer a bit, but don't recommend doing that as it's an example of leaking goroutine.